# Insert random id into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

I'm trying to insert records in my database and I am using this code:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("my_db");

$patient_array = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$patient_array[$row['account_id']] = array("lastname" => $row['lastname'], 
"firstname" => $row['firstname']);
}

foreach($time_table as $tid => $t){
echo array_rand($patient_array, 1);
echo $tid."====".$t["from"]." - " . $t["to"]."<br />";

$sql = "INSERT INTO appointment (appt_id, appt_date, appt_time, appt_doctor, 
patient_id, appt_time_end) VALUES ('', '".$appt_date."', '".$t["from"]."', 
'".$doc."', '".$tid."', '".$t["to"]."')";

mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

This one is properly inserting but for the "patient_id" I want to store random ids. $tid gives me random output but when I check the database, it's not the same; it's showing ids in descending order. I tried using Order by Rand() but I can't figure out how to make it working. Any idea? Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

EDIT: I am getting the patient_id from another table, which is the accounts table to be passed into appointment table. I was able to select random patient ids but how can I insert it to another table, in random order also.

Comment: where is the value of the `PatientID` coming from? Is there any range for random generated `ID`?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Comment: order by rand() is bad solution. Check this http://www.electrictoolbox.com/msyql-alternative-order-by-rand/ Where `$time_table` is assigned I couldn't find it?

Comment: Are you really need PatientID to be random? Probably you already have some table for patients with primary key which is what you want in 99.999999% situations. Those who are in 0.00001% already know how to deal with their situation.

Answer (score 1):

For getting random id why cant you use the functoin `uniqid()` in PHP

```
$randomID = uniqid()
```

Please refer the following link,

[Random/Unique ID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can add an extra column called 'time' where you put the UNIX time for example so that when you order by the 'time' you get the random ids in the order you wrote them in the table..
I suggest you to add the time is really useful to have it stored somewhere!

if you want them not in random order but in a precise order I don't actually understand why you wanna use the random id though!

Answer (score 0):

I would make a database field called id which has the
AUTO_INCREMENT attribute

You can add the column with the following command

```
alter table appointment add (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your responses, but I've figured out what's the answer for this. Here's my code modification:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
//I changed this...
//$patient_array[$row['patient_id']] = array("lastname" => $row['lastname'], "firstname" => $row['firstname']);
//to this:
$patient_array[] = $row['patient_id'];
}

foreach($time_table as $tid => $t){
/*
removed this, since it's just an output to check what's happening inside 
the 'rand'      
echo array_rand($patient_array, 1);
echo $tid."====".$t["from"]." - " . $t["to"]."<br />";
*/

//added these...
$rand = array_rand($patient_array); //randomize patient id
$patient_id = $patient_array[$rand];
print_r($patient_id); //displays randomized ids

//and now was able to INSERT RANDOM patient ids
$sql = "INSERT INTO appointment (appt_id, appt_date, appt_time, appt_doctor, patient_id, appt_time_end) VALUES ('', '".$appt_date."', '".$t["from"]."', '".$doc."', '".$patient_id."', '".$t["to"]."')";

mysql_query($sql);
}
```